# How to user Viewer js in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, laravel, viewer

Hello I'm trying to display PDF documents with [ViewerJS plugin](http://viewerjs.org/) but it doesn't work properly. As documentation says I have `<iframe id="viewer" src = "{{URL::to('/')}}/ViewerJS/#../uploads/files/{{$video->source}}" width='100%' height='600' allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen></iframe>`
I have ViewerJS folder in public folder and my pdf files in public/uploads/files folder. When I use this url it shows my page in frame instead of document. Where is a mistake?

Comment: Dear @Zolax are you find the solution.if then guide me how to open docx/doc file in browser using viewerJS.

Answer (score 7):

Although this is old question, I would like to share how I got that working:

Step 1: Download ViewerJs - http://viewerjs.org/releases/ViewerJS-latest.zip

Step 2: Extract this in public directory of Laravel (I used it with Laravel 4.0)

Step 3: Now, extract another copy in Views folder. That means, you will have ViewerJs library at two locations. One inside public (public/ViewerJs) folder and another will be at (views/ViewerJs)

Step 4: Add below code in your app/routes.php

```
//DocumentViewer Library
Route::any('ViewerJS/{all?}', function(){

    return View::make('ViewerJS.index');
});
```

Step 5: Now, add any sample PDF file in your public folder (for testing purpose)

Step 6: Open below URL in your browser

http://example.com/ViewerJS/index.html#../demodoc.pdf

Please replace example.com (in my case this was localhost/webapp) by your project path and replace demodoc.pdf by name of sample PDF file that you added in public folder.

That's it. This will work fine.

Comment: Is there any simple way to know when document finished loading ?

Comment: Dear @aquasmit First of all great work.Secondly sir what should I do for docx.I give the link but it shows blank,mean dont show the the text in the docx document.Kindly help me.

Comment: Thanks @aquasmit, you save my day. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you @aquasmit

Answer (score 0):

You should do as follows:

1. copy the content of ViewerJS folder e.g in your public/viewerjs
2. edit PluginLoader.js, ODFViewerPlugin.js, PDFViewerPlugin.js and search for the string ./ and change it to the relative path of the directory, in my example **viewer/** 
    
   Ex.: in PluginLoader.js, you will find:

   `loadPlugin('./ODFViewerPlugin', function () {
                   Plugin = ODFViewerPlugin;
               });`

   replace this to:

   `loadPlugin('viewerjs/ODFViewerPlugin', function () {
                   Plugin = ODFViewerPlugin;
               });`
3. create a GET route like: `Route::get('/ViewerJS/{all?}', array('as' => 'pdfViewer', 'uses' => 'YOURCONTROLLER@pdfViewer'));`
4. create the method in you controller like:

   `public function pdfViewer()
   {
     return View::make('pdfview.view');
   }`
5. Create your the view and paste the entire content of the index.html, it's inside the ViewerJS folder. Don't forget to replace all css and javascript file references with:

   `{{ asset('viewerjs/viewer.css') }}`

   `{{ asset('viewerjs/viewer.js') }}`

   `{{ asset('viewerjs/PluginLoader.js') }}`
6. Call the route like: http://www.xxxxx.com/ViewerJS#YOUR_PATH_TO_THE_PDF_FILE_UNDER_THE_PUBLIC_FOLDER 
   **example:** uploads/pdfs/test.pdf 
    
   **Note** that you don't have to specify public/uploads/pdfs/test.pdf !!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the PDF's name to the path, as well. For example:

```
http://www.xxxxx.com/ViewerJS#YOUR_PATH_TO_THE_PDF_FILE_UNDER_THE_PUBLIC_FOLDER/NAME_FILEP
```